# POST request with AFNetworking 2.0 - AFHTTPSessionManager

Tags: objective-c, json, post, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Hej,

I am struggling with doing a POST request to the parse REST API. I am using AFNetworking 2.0. My code for the AFHTTPSessionManager Subclass looks as follows:

```
+ (ParseAPISession *)sharedSession {
     static ParseAPISession *sharedSession = nil;
     static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
     dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
         sharedSession = [[ParseAPISession alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kSDFParseAPIBaseURLString]];
    });
   return sharedSession;
}
```

And:

```
- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (self) {
       [self.requestSerializer setValue:kSDFParseAPIApplicationId forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
       [self.requestSerializer setValue:kSDFParseAPIKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
   }

   return self;
}
```

I am doing the request like this:

```
[[ParseAPISession sharedSession] POST:@"ClassName" parameters: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"name", @"name", nil] 
                              success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id abc) {
                                  NSLog(@"%@", abc);
                              } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                                  NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
```

Doing this I always get this kind of error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x8c72420 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Since the GET Request works like a charm I am quite confused why I can’t POST something. Can anybody halp me with this problem?

Best regards!

**UPDATE**

Happily after testing around a lot this Error message isn't displayed anymore, unfortuatelly another appeared:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8b96d40>
{ URL: https://api.parse.com/1/users }
{ status code: 400, 
headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Access-Control-Request-Method" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 130;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 30 Oct 2013 20:01:58 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.4.2";
    "Set-Cookie" = "_parse_session=BAh7BkkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlNjIxZjUxMzY3NWVhZWJmMDYyYWYwMGJiZTQ3MThmMWE%3D--851bd31b07e7dba2c5f83bb13a8d801ecbea42c4; domain=.parse.com; path=/; expires=Fri, 29-Nov-2013 20:01:58 GMT; secure; HttpOnly";
    Status = "400 Bad Request";
    "X-Runtime" = "0.060910";
    "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
} }
```

Can anyone tell me what the Status: 400 Bad Request is telling me and how I can get rid of it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error means that your POST request went through, the server is successfully returning you some data, which `NSJSONSerialization` is having trouble parsing.

You probably need to set your `AFJSONResponseSerializer` to allow JSON fragments.

In the `init` method of your `AFHTTPSessionManager` subclass:

```
AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
[self setResponseSerializer:responseSerializer];
```

If this doesn't work, you probably have an encoding issue.  From the `NSJSONSerialization` class reference:

> The data must be in one of the 5 supported encodings listed in the JSON specification: UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, UTF-32BE. The data may or may not have a BOM. The most efficient encoding to use for parsing is UTF-8, so if you have a choice in encoding the data passed to this method, use UTF-8.

Check the encoding type sent by your server.

Finally, you can either set breakpoints inside of AFNetworking, or set up [AFNetworkActivityLogger](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger), which will log requests as they are sent and received to your console.  This tool is incredibly helpful for debugging this type of issue.

Comment: (It's also possible the server is returning something other than JSON, in which case you don't want to use `AFJSONResponseSerializer` at all.)

Comment: Hej, thank you for your response! I tried this out but in the moment I get another kind of Error messages (see update above) where I think the original problem isn't the main problem any more .... maybe you can help me with this as well?

Comment: You should ask a separate question for this.  Your request is not the proper format for Parse, and the server is rejecting it.  (IE, you now have a Parse issue, not an AFNetworking issue.)

Comment: Try to set the AFJSONRequestSerializer to your AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, it worked for me: manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

in the `AFHTTPSessionManager` subclass initialise it with the following serialisers:

`[self setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];
 [self setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];`