# How see the error of a json POST with AFNetworking?

Tags: json, ios7, django-rest-framework, afnetworking-2

After look at [POST request with AFNetworking 2.0 - AFHTTPSessionManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680193/post-request-with-afnetworking-2-0-afhttpsessionmanager) I can't see where the error message can be found.

This is my setup:

```
-(id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:DebugURLString];

        self.session = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

        self.session.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
        self.session.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) login:(NSString *)email pwd:(NSString *)pwd result:(void(^)(NSError* result))handler
{
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"username": email, @"password":pwd};

    [self.session POST:@"auth/api-token/" parameters:params
               success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
                   NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
                   handler(nil);
               }
               failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                   NSLog(@"%@", task);
                   NSLog(@"%@", error.userInfo);
                   handler(error);
               }];
}
```

I call http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#tokenauthentication, directly the `rest_framework.authtoken.views.obtain_auth_token` that ask for a username & password and return a token.

If the user/pass is correct this work fine. But if not I get:

```
error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey]
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xb388f20> { URL: http://localhost:8000/auth/api-token/ } { status code: 400, headers {
    Allow = "POST, OPTIONS";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Sat, 11 Jan 2014 02:14:13 GMT";
    Server = "WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.5";
    Vary = "Accept, Cookie";
} }
```

However, when I do the same call with python + requests, I get:

```
{u'non_field_errors': [u'Unable to login with provided credentials.']}
```

But I don't find it in the `NSError`.

Also, despite that I set `responseSerializer`, it report in the task:

```
(lldb) po task.response
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xb388f20> { URL: http://localhost:8000/auth/api-token/ } { status code: 400, headers {
    Allow = "POST, OPTIONS";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Sat, 11 Jan 2014 02:14:13 GMT";
    Server = "WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.5";
    Vary = "Accept, Cookie";
```

Instead of the JSon one. What I need to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hit a *quirk* of `AFNetworking` v2 — by default the response body is not passed into the failure block. [Check the discussion on Github for the details](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1397).

The bottom line is you need to subclass `AFJSONResponseSerializer` in order to add the response data you need to the `userInfo` dictionary of the `NSError` during `responseObjectForResponse:data:error:`. (You'll then be able to access it.)

Your question prompted me to revisit the [Github issue (same as above)](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1397). There's now [a blog post](http://blog.gregfiumara.com/archives/239) and [a repo with an example subclass](https://github.com/Hackmodford/HMFJSONResponseSerializerWithData) available.

I hope all that helps.

`AFNetworking` v2 is great; this behaviour was *an oddity* when adopting it. My initial thought was *"This can't be right"*, but I think the underlying reasoning is that you are *encouraged* to create your own response serialisers. The shipped examples are fairly light-weight. It's easy create your own, and the response serialiser is a good place to encapsulate network related logic that otherwise ends up back in your application.

Comment: This did the trick, however the body return a NSString instead of a JSON/Dictionary...

Comment: You get given an NSData. If you've got a string you converted it yourself somewhere. If you want an NSDictionary you could use NSJSONSerialization there instead.